# Renaming/Stripping version from artifacts while downloading in Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I have a particular use-case where I need to make sure that a particular maven artifact when downloaded as a dependency using Gradle is renamed, specifically the version is stripped off. I have seen many use-cases online but none helps me in my use-case.

My use-case is a Spring Boot application and the dependency is hosted in a Apache Archiva server. Originally I uploaded the jar as `artifact.jar` but gradle downloads it as `artifact-0.1.2.jar`. Now, this jar will not work if it is renamed so I need to make sure that it is artifact.jar` when it is downloaded.

My question is very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40024088/strip-version-number-from-certain-dependencies-in-gradle-custom-plugin), but the difference lies in the fact that my dependencies won't be copied to `build/lib`. For the spring boot app, my dependencies are compiled by a custom task by a spring boot plugin into a fat jar. Also, while developing I will run another custom task given by the plugin which although does not generate a fat jar, but does not copy over the artifacts anyway (probably reads from the Gradle download folder).

Do note, I don't want to strip off the version number of all dependencies, just a particular one.

Is there any way to achieve what I want.

I believe Maven has [something](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-mojo.html#stripVersion) of this sort.